# How to turn a git repo into a ppa

Tags: git, qt, deb, ppa

Suppose I have a git repo, the instructions for building are:

```
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential git mesa-common-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libsdl2-dev libsamplerate0-dev
cd ~
wget http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.0/5.0.2/qt-linux-opensource-5.0.2-x86-offline.run
chmod +x qt-linux-opensource-5.0.2-x86-offline.run
./qt-linux-opensource-5.0.2-x86-offline.run
git clone --recursive https://github.com/foo/foo.git
mkdir foo-build
cd foo-build
qmake ../foo -r
make -j8
```

After which all of QT's files reside in a single directory (chosen by the user during graphical install) the application's files reside in `~/foo/bin` and the application can be launched by running `~/foo/bin/foo`.

(The QT graphical installer is required because the Ubuntu repos do not have an up-to-date version.)

How would I alter this process to package the source into a source package (obviously) which I can upload to my Launchpad PPA.

Comment: I would suggest not doing this.  In fact, very strongly recommend it.  If you need to ask this question, you do not know anywhere near enough to succeed, and will need months (at least) of reading and learning.  Instead, either 1. search for an existing ubuntu ppa with a newer Qt or 2. wait until ubuntu releases an updated set of Qt packages....you almost certainly do not **need** the updated Qt and if you have written some other code to rely on it, then fix it so that it works with the older version.

Comment: btw, take install instructions from git repos with a huge grain of salt.  they're written by devs who only give a damn about their own code and think the system it is going to run on is an obstacle to be worked around and screwed with, no matter what that does to other programs that system might need to run.  devs are short-sighted and focused only on their own stuff.  distros necessarily focus on the bigger picture of enabling lots of different programs to run without conflict.

Comment: http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html . Also, it might be good to download the source code for the Ubuntu-localized qt (using `apt-get source`) and see what patches they apply.